# How to detect a view as parent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Consider a textView, how to detect the parent of textView using condition or some logic?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    TextView text=new TextView(Context);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say detect the textView's parent? is this textView already in your layout?

Comment: If I keep on removing and adding textview to parent layout. At particular point of time, I need to know whether it is added to parent or not. (using code). Virtually I can find, but I need by using code to verify

Comment: By that do you mean that you need to check if it has a parent or not?

Comment: I have posted an answer, please try it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Answer the question as per my understanding:

If you are adding and removing a control a lot of times to get the View's parent you can use the parent property in your case:

```
text.Parent;
```

Note that this will be null if there is no parent.

So before using this parent in any way, I would suggest you null check it.

```
if(text.Parent!=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textView.getParent();
```

If parent is null, it is not added to the paren.

Answer (score 0):

You may detect a view as parent using `text.Parent`, so the code is like this:

```
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.Text = "Text";

    IViewParent layout = text.Parent;

    if (layout == layout2) //To detect whether it is added to parent or not.
    {
        text.Text = "I am added to layout2";
        Console.WriteLine("layout2 is the parent of text");
    }
    else {
        layout2.AddView(text);
    }
```